# Instantiation inside of a class vs Dependency Injection (for testability)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

> This is quite a synthetic example, however I had similar condintions in production code.

Program converts applicants to employees.
In the loop we call concrete, dedicated implementation of AccountConvertor that is aggregated inside of an applicant class (e.g. `ManagerAccountConvertor` for `Manager`). It's highly unlikely that we would ever use something other than `ManagerAccountConvertor` for converting `Manager`. Is there any sense to inject concrete converter for concrete manager every single time instead of keeping inline instantiation and just test it as is?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IApplicant> applicants = new List<IApplicant>
        {
            new Clerk {FirstName = "Nik", LastName = "Corey"},
            new Manager {FirstName = "Sue", LastName = "Storm"},
            new Executive {FirstName = "Nancy", LastName = "Roman"}
        };

        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        foreach (var ap in applicants)
        {
            Employee employee = ap.AccountConvertor.Convert();

            employees.Add(employee);
        }

        foreach (var emp in employees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{emp.FirstName} {emp.LastName}: {emp.EmailAddress} IsManager: {emp.IsManager} IsExecutive: {emp.IsExecutive}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IApplicant
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    IAccountConvertor AccountConvertor { get; set; }
}

public interface IAccountConvertor
{
    Employee Convert();
}
```

Comment: You can never test these units independently if you stick with this pattern, and while it is unlikely that you will change from `ManagerAccountConvertor` I would leave the option there (SOLID design). Also the argument in your call to `AccountConvertor.Convert()` is redundant.

Comment: Use some form of convention, based on some parameter or property inject the concrete implementation. While registering the implementation register the lifetime as `Scoped`, so that same instance is used.

Comment: map `Interface` with your `DTO` classes and inject them using those interfaces.

Comment: This question will likely be closed as off-topic or opinion-based... From your description it seems that AccountConvertor has no external dependencies; therefore I see no reason to even put it behind an interface, let alone inject it via DI. YMMV.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane Why not test converter and applicant as a coehisive unit (integration testing)? In addition we can unit test convertor separatly. This is exactly why I posted this question at the first place. Isn't it silly to apply 'D' from SOLID everywhere without even thinking? And yes, the argument was redundunt - fixed.

Comment: @jeroenh There are different types of convertors for different types of applicants, they all inherit and implement the interface. `ClerkConvertor` for `Clerk`, `ExecutiveConvertor` for `Executive` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the **IAccountConverter** is the same for all implementations for **IApplicant**, then it would be a performance advantage to not have to instantiate the concrete implementation of **IAccountConverter** for each employee *instance*, but only one for each employee *type*. There is also overhead for retrieving an instance from the injection repository. You'll have to consider if the overhead is significant enough for the number or employees the solution will convert.

Comment: Performance is not relevant for my question. It's all about simplicity of design.